Slow moving asian movie about hitman?
I'm trying to remember the name of a recent Asian film. It's definitely not Japanese, Korean, or Chinese/HK - maybe Thai or Indonesian?
It follows a hitman who has returned to the tiny village where he is from. 
There's very little action, much more of a character study, though there IS a knife fight in a field.
At one point the main character digs up a box of his childhood belongings, which includes a knife (no guns in the movie at all).
His best friend lives in a dry-docked boat. 
The cinematography is stunning, and it opens with a long take of a child walking along a beach, visible through a hole in large piece of cloth.
I'd guess it was made post-2010.
Any clues?
